# Arduino mkr1000 wifi communication with Raspberry pi b

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, udp

I ve been using arduino mkr1000 to send udp packet via local network on Raspberry pi b local port 6661. But it is not receiving any data. I want to check if the udp packets that are being sent are received or not.

Comment: welcome @Hamza Shafiq...if you can provide more information and the code you've written so far...(for more information you can visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/